# Confusion regarding Change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The question says,

> "Let $X=\{x_1,x_2,…,x_n\}$ and $X’=\{x’_1,x’_2,…,x’_n\}$ be two bases of $F^n$.  Let $A=[x_1 :…:x_n]$ and $B=[x’_1:…:x']$. Show that the matrix of transition from $X$ to $X’$ is $A^{-1}B$.
>   "

My attempt:
If $R$ be the matrix of transition from $X$ to $X’$ and if $a$ and $b$ be the representation of a certain vector of $F^n$ with respect to the coordinate system of $X$ and $X’$ respectively then $Rb=a$. 
So, $Rx’_1= x_1$,$Rx'_2=x_2$,….$Rx’_n=x_n$.
Which implies $RB=A$ ,i.e. $R=AB^{-1}$.

What am I missing here?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The transition matrix, $R$, from $X$ to $X'$, means that $XR=X'$ *not* $RX'=X$.

Comment: Is there any difference between matrix of transition and transformation matrix?